# Excel Solver Looping through rows in formulas

Tags: excel, solver, vba

```
D       G
529.01  531.27
523.26  524.33
515.00  516.18
507.00  507.24
497.99  503.48
504.76  504.92
494.94  495.98
498.84  502.98
494.65  503.23
505.57  505.68
500.01  508.19
511.00  512.5
507.25  519.28
521.48  536.33
535.59  542.17
538.53  539



Formula in L14: =SUMPRODUCT($L$13:$P$13,$L$12:$P$12)

Formula in L13: =SUMPRODUCT($L$7:$L$11,D7:D11)
Formula in M13: =SUMPRODUCT($M$7:$M$11,D7:D11)
Formula in N13: =SUMPRODUCT($N$7:$N$11,D7:D11)
Formula in O13: =SUMPRODUCT($O$7:$O$11,D7:D11)
Formula in P13: =SUMPRODUCT($P$7:$P$11,D7:D11)
```

My Solver Macro Code is:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$I$13", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$L$7:$P$12", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$I$13", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$L$7:$P$12", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve True
```

My Column I is:

```
=G12-$L$14
```

My Column K is:

```
=$L$14
```

The rows D7:D11 should increment by one every-time we go down one row. This way we keep going down until we hit D105 and that's when the column ends.
I currently have Solver running on one objective function value, but I need to do this for every cell in column G excluding the first 5 cells in G.

The problem I am facing is that the cells that I have in Solver's objective function has other cells that are also a function of formulas, so I can't figure out how to change the formulas by iterating through them and writing the solver answer into column K before moving on.

For example, we start at G6 because we are using D1-5's values to get G6's value. The formula would look like:
**

```
Formula in L13: =SUMPRODUCT($L$7:$L$11,D7:D11)
Formula in M13: =SUMPRODUCT($M$7:$M$11,D7:D11)
Formula in N13: =SUMPRODUCT($N$7:$N$11,D7:D11)
Formula in O13: =SUMPRODUCT($O$7:$O$11,D7:D11)
Formula in P13: =SUMPRODUCT($P$7:$P$11,D7:D11)
```

**

Now Solver should change the formulas for G7 like this:

```
Formula in L13: =SUMPRODUCT($L$7:$L$11,D8:D12)
Formula in M13: =SUMPRODUCT($M$7:$M$11,D8:D12)
Formula in N13: =SUMPRODUCT($N$7:$N$11,D8:D12)
Formula in O13: =SUMPRODUCT($O$7:$O$11,D8:D12)
Formula in P13: =SUMPRODUCT($P$7:$P$11,D8:D12)
```

For G8 Solver should change the formula to:

```
Formula in L13: =SUMPRODUCT($L$7:$L$11,D9:D13)
Formula in M13: =SUMPRODUCT($M$7:$M$11,D9:D13)
Formula in N13: =SUMPRODUCT($N$7:$N$11,D9:D13)
Formula in O13: =SUMPRODUCT($O$7:$O$11,D9:D13)
Formula in P13: =SUMPRODUCT($P$7:$P$11,D9:D13)
```

**How can I iterate through the formulas like this while using Solver?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you somewhere. Just set your range to something named and add a looper variable that increments the RowShift by 1... play with this in a test spreadsheet...

```
Dim workingRange As Range
Set workingRange = Sheets(1).Range("A7:A11")

'alternate version, assuming you are in some sort of i-j double loop
Set workingRange = Sheets.Range( Cells(7+i,7+j) , Cells(11+i,7+j) ) 'G7:G11

'now you have some options....
workingRange.Value = "testing"
workingRange.Formula = "=Abs(B1)"

'if working with cells() and indices, the R1C1 style may be for you...
workingRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=  {formula here} "
```

Here's the documentation for R1C1 notation, it's super easy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx

Regards, Kevin